# Can't use Bootstrap in React?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to use a button in a reactJS file. This is the code I have

```
export class Add extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">
          Add
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But react is giving me:

```
'Button' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
```

I've included bootstrap in the dependcies  in package.json, as well as popper.js and jquery, and I've tried npm install bootstrap. I also made sure to

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

in my mainJs file.

I also tried using  with no luck.

Comment: Of course you can [use bootstrap and react](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react#react-and-bootstrap) together.

Comment: I know it's possible, I meant to say I'm *unable to*

Comment: Button is from `react-bootstrap`, install that and you can remove jquery and popper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMR,

Looks like you are trying to use components so i believe you are trying to use React-Bootstrap.  Here it goes:  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction

Run following to install it first:

```
    npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

then include it in your file:

```
    import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
```

EDIT:  Adding styles as suggested in comments:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Also add the syles in index.js file<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Voila, that seems to have fixed it. Didn't realize *bootstrap* and *react-bootstrap* were different haha. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But I recommend you check this library out. [ReactStrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)